# How to indicate in class diagram that an object will have versions?

Tags: uml

I have a Text class. Objects of this class will have many versions. So there will be history of text changes.
How to indicate this on class diagram properly?
I need to show when it was changed and by who? Create class for text change? It is littlebit strange. Generalization?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this diagram below? (I'm sorry if I am misunderstanding your description.)
Also, the [Memento design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) may help you.

[image]

Comment: You'll still need a timedate field in TextChange as one of the requirement is "to show when it was changed".